# Class Preserving Automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to prove that the set of all class preserving automorphisms of G, denoted by Aut_{c}(G) , is a normal subgroup of Aut (G)?

Answer (score 2):

I assume by the phrasing of the question that you understand why $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ acts on the set $\mathcal{C}$ of conjugacy classes in $G$ (if not, stop right now and prove that if $\beta\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, then $x,y\in G$ are conjugate if and only if $\beta(x),\beta(y)\in G$ are conjugate).

Now, let $C\in\mathcal{C}$ be a conjugacy class, $\beta\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\gamma\in\mathrm{Aut}_c(G)$. As $\beta^{-1}(C)\in\mathcal{C}$, we have $$\gamma(\beta^{-1}(C))=\beta^{-1}(C)$$
since $\gamma$ fixes conjugacy classes. Now, compute $\beta\gamma\beta^{-1}(C)=C$:

> $$\beta\gamma\beta^{-1}(C)=\beta(\underbrace{\gamma(\beta^{-1}(C))}_{\beta^{-1}(C)})=\beta(\beta^{-1}(C))=C$$

It follows that, $\beta\gamma\beta^{-1}\in\mathrm{Aut}_c(G)$ as required.